# Exclude different named field in class mapping using Dozer

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I have a 
class A with field "mapEntries" - it is a list, 
class B with "entries" - it is a wrapper class around list.

I need to map class A to class B. While mapping I need to exclude the "entries" field.
How can I do this? I have tried both one way and both way exclude but it's not working.

The full(both side) exclude seems to work only when the fields have same name in both the src and dest classes.

One Way exclude:

`<field-exclude type="one-way">
            <a>mapEntries</a>
            <b>entries</b>
        </field-exclude>`

Both way exclude:

```
    <field-exclude>
        <a>mapEntries</a>
        <b>entries</b>
    </field-exclude>
```

I have lot of other fields as well in these classes hence using wildcard is not an option.

```
<mapping map-null="false">
    <class-a>ClientClass</class-a>
    <class-b>ProductClass</class-b>

    <field-exclude>
        <a>mapEntries</a>
        <b>entries</b>
    </field-exclude>
</mapping>
```

With this mapping, fields don't get excluded. The product class has getter/setter as setMapEntries() and getMapEntries(). This seems to be the cause. The control does reach in getMapEntries(). I cannot change product code.
If I rename Client field as entries, keeping both client and product field same, it works properly and the mapping gets excluded.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the XML configuration you have tried?

Comment: Are you sure your XML configuration is being read in correctly to the mapper before use?

Comment: Also, what version of Dozer are you using?

Comment: Dozer version is 5.4.0.
All other XML mappings is working properly. The basic problem am facing is different named fields are not getting excluded.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If so, could you post the stack trace?

Comment: There is no exception. @JamesB

Comment: That is bizarre. What happens if you remove all XML configuration for the mapping of these two fields?

Comment: XML config for this field is only to exclude its mapping.

field-exclude is ignored for this field. So I put it or not, auto-mapping happens which I don't want. @JamesB